# PowerShell: How to pass in blacklist as command parameter for Get-ChildItem -Exclude flag

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the list of files in a folder while excluding certain files using the 
script files.ps1:

```
Param(
    [string]$blacklist,
    [string]$build_path
 )

$filesToBuild = Get-ChildItem $build_path -Recurse -Exclude $blacklist

foreach ($file in $filesToBuild) {
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "File: $file"
}
```

If I call the script using the command

```
.\files.ps1 -build_path "C:\SomeFolder" -blacklist 'Dev*'
```

it will exclude files with `Dev*` but if I pass in a list of files `-blacklist 'Dev*, Microsoft*'` it will not ignore any of the files. I tried without and without quotes.

However, hardcoding it into the script works:

```
$filesToBuild = Get-ChildItem $build_path -Recurse -Exclude Dev*, Microsoft*
```

What is the proper format to pass in a list of strings for the `-Exclude` flag through the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at `Get-Help Get-ChildItem` I see that the `-Exclude` parameter accepts an array of strings, so instead of passing it `'Dev*, Microsoft*'` you should be passing it `'Dev*','Microsoft*'`. You will also have to update your parameter to accept an array of strings.

```
Param(
    [string[]]$blacklist,
    [string]$build_path
 )

$filesToBuild = Get-ChildItem $build_path -Recurse -Exclude $blacklist

foreach ($file in $filesToBuild) {
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "File: $file"
}

.\files.ps1 -build_path "C:\SomeFolder" -blacklist 'Dev*','Microsoft*'
```